# Getting multiple params from user

Tags: haskell

How do I get multiple params from user in haskell?

```
module Main where
main :: IO ()
main =  do
        putStrLn "Please enter param1: "
        param1 <- getLine 
        putStrLn "Please enter param2: "
        param2 <- getLine  
        putStrLn  $ "you entered" ++ param1 ++ "param 2:" ++ param2
```

I am using http://www.compileonline.com/compile_haskell_online.php to feed in params.

I am not sure if the program is wrong or the STDINPUT is not fine.

can someone guide me here.

All I get this is this :

> Please enter param1:  Please enter param2:  demo: : hGetLine:
>   end of file

The output is not even printed.

```
STDIN Input: 123 231
```

Comment: Are you running this in the interpreter?  You should compile it if you aren't then give that a try.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I am using compileonline.com and i have no issues compiling just that the output is null all the time

Comment: It looks like you're adding the `haskell-platform` and `real-world-haskell` tags to all your questions. Please don't add tags that don't apply -- e.g. none of your questions used any libraries at all, and so clearly aren't Platform-specific.

Comment: @danielwagner. sorry about the tags i am very new to haskell and i do not have idea what tag to include. May be thats y i am getting so many downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the input is 1 line, while you're expecting 2 lines. Either put the input on two lines or change your code to be

```
module Main where
main :: IO ()
main =  do
    line <- getLine
    let
        params = words line
        param1 = params !! 0
        param2 = params !! 1
    putStrLn  $ "you entered" ++ param1 ++ "param 2:" ++ param2
```

This takes the single line of stdin and splits it by space.

Comment: Damn something new everyday

Answer (score 2):

Your `compileonline.com` site does not support multiple lines in `stdin`. If you remove the second `getLine` and `param2` your program works.

The error you are seeing relates to `stdin` being closed before the second `getLine` is completed.

Any site that spells it 'Haskel' is probably not a good one.